# Enabling PostgreSQL with custom PHP on Windows Azure

Tags: php, postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a PHP web app connects to a PostgreSQL on **Azure Website**. Azure Website doesn't support to customize system level extensions to be enabled using `.user.ini` given within the `wwwroot` folder.

I went ahead with custom PHP installation and did the following

1. Copied PHP binaries as described under \bin\php folder
2. Modified under `\bin\phpphp.ini` has been modified with.

   - `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
   - `extension=php_pgsql.dll`
3. Added `*.php*` key and value `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe` under handler mappings
4. Added PHP extensions key `PHP_EXTENSIONS` and value `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php\ext` under `app settings` configuration.

But when I look in to PHPInfo(), all the details are taken as configured but the extensions are not loaded.

I followed the guideline mentioned here - [Using custom PHP Runtime](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#UseCustomPHP)

How to resolve this?

Comment: generally after changes is done server is restarted to adhere to new changes , contact your hosting provider that would help

Comment: I have restarted the service. It doesn't help!

Comment: Have you restarted APache , which hosting you are using windows or linux ??

Comment: @NaveenThally It's a "website" from Azure. It comes with default PHP runtime and IIS. We don't have much control over it

Comment: check out this link buddy http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php it may help

Comment: @NaveenThally This is specifically on Azure environment!

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed the two different ways of bringing another dynamic extension to Azure Websites.

If you upload the `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` binary to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin` then add `PHP_Extensions` to the **App Settings** with the value `bin\php_pdo_pgsql.dll` it should fix your issues. if you have multiple extensions you want to enable, separate them with commas in the same **App Setting** value field

Alternatively, you could upload your own runtime, then you have full control over the php.ini which in included in the directory you upload the runtime to as described in [using custom php runtime](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#UseCustomPHP)

Do note these are **two** separate options.

Comment: This will work. Note that the dlls you need can be aquired from IIS compliant non-thread safe PHP installs. Get the ones you need for the particular PHP version your Azure website uses: windows.php.net/download/